# Сравнить даты изменения локального и удаленно файла. PHP

Tags: php, http

PHP.
Есть два файла - локальный и удаленный:

```
$file1='1.txt';
$file2='http://site.ru/2.txt';
```

Необходимо сравнить дату-время изменения обоих файлов, и если $file2 изменен позже (более новый), то вывести сообщение "ок".

Как сделать это правильнее?

Comment: ну для начала вам надо иметь фтп доступ до `$file2` чтобы получить дату изменения.

Comment: доступ к удаленному файлу по http

Answer (score 1):

```
function modified($url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
    if ($timestamp != -1):
        echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
    else:
            echo 'No timestamp found';
        endif;


}
echo modified('http://myurl.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать вот так:

```
$file1 = '1.txt';
$file2 = 'http://site.ru/2.txt';

$f1Time = filemtime($file1);
$h = get_headers($file2, 1); 
if ($h && strstr($h[0], '200') !== FALSE)  $f2Time = strtotime($h['Last-Modified']);

if ($f2Time > $f1Time) echo 'OK';
```

- для простоты, предполагается, что оба файла существуют и доступны.